# Running nightwatch tests on a create-react-app on travis

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, nightwatch.js, create-react-app, npm-scripts

I have an issue Running nightwatch tests on a create-react-app server (`npm start`) on travis. I'm starting the creat-react-app with

.travis.yml:

```
before_script:
  - npm --prefix ./client start ./client &
script: npm run test-ci
```

however when nightwatch runs I am always getting

```
Starting the development server...
Starting selenium server... Warning: The 'no-use-before-declare' rule requires type information.
ts-loader: Using typescript@2.5.3 and /home/travis/build/client/tsconfig.json
started - PID:  4017

You can now view app in the browser.
  Local:            http://localhost:3000/
  On Your Network:  http://172.17.0.3:3000/
Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server
Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
{ Error: socket hang up
```

However the starting & running the nightwatch tests locally works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with Chrome, not a problem with react or Nightwatch.

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8836